# Appium testing cannot access field "InvalidElementState"

Tags: angular, typescript, mocha.js, appium, nativescript

I'm using Appium with typescript + mocha + chai for my tests.

I have four fields on the one tab and I'm trying to access the forth textfield through a test and keep getting an error.

View;

```
    <Label text="Asset Name"></Label>
    <TextField automationText="name" hint="Asset Name" [(ngModel)]="_assetItem.name" class="input"></TextField>

    <Label text="Purchase Price"></Label>
    <TextField automationText="gross" hint="Asset Purchase Price" [(ngModel)]="_assetItem.gross_cents" class="input"></TextField>

    <Label text="Comment"></Label>
    <TextField automationText="comment" hint="Asset Comment" [(ngModel)]="_assetItem.comment" class="input"></TextField>

  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Test;

```
import { AppiumDriver, createDriver, SearchOptions, nsCapabilities } from "nativescript-dev-appium";
import { assert } from "chai";

const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');

describe("Asset Create", () => {
    let driver: AppiumDriver;

    before(async function(){
        nsCapabilities.testReporter.context = this; 
        driver = await createDriver(); // wait for the driver instance to be created
    });

    after(async function () {
        await driver.quit();    //  destroy the driver instance
        console.log("Quit driver!");
    });

    afterEach(async function () {
        if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
            await driver.logTestArtifacts(this.currentTest.title);
        }
    });

    describe("After login", () => {

        before(async function () {
            // Enter user
            const nameField = await driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("email");
            await nameField.sendKeys("test");

            // Enter password
            const passwordField = await driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("password");
            await passwordField.sendKeys("password");

            // Login
            const btnLoginTap = await driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("btnLogin");
            await btnLoginTap.click();
        });

        it.only("creates new asset", async function () {
            const btnManualNavTap = await driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("btnNewAsset");
            await btnManualNavTap.click();

            const nameField = await driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("name");
            await nameField.sendKeys("PI");

            const grossField = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("gross");
            await grossField.sendKeys("5800");

            const commentField = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("comment");
            await commentField.sendKeys("Used as a camera");
```

Error;

```
Exited from appium

  0 passing (42s)
  1 failing

  1) Asset Create
       After login
         creates new asset:
     Error: [element.sendKeys("Used as a camera")] Error response status: 12, 
InvalidElementState - An element command could not be completed because the 
element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element). 
Selenium error: Cannot set the element to 'Used as a camera'. Did you interact 
with the correct element?
      at exports.newError (node_modules/wd/lib/utils.js:152:13)
      at /home/map7/code/asset_management/node_modules/wd/lib/callbacks.js:36:19
      at /home/map7/code/asset_management/node_modules/wd/lib/webdriver.js:196:5
      at Request._callback (node_modules/wd/lib/http-utils.js:89:7)
      at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
      at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
      at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
      at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1085:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ e2e: `node ./node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/check-dev-deps.js &&  tsc -p e2e  &&  mocha --opts ./e2e/config/mocha.opts  "--runType" "device.samsung"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/map7/.npm/_logs/2019-11-14T02_53_23_647Z-debug.log
~/code/asset_management (asset_tabs✗) %
```

If however I remove the purchase price and comment labels then it finds the element no problem. When I'm watching the test it doesn't cover it with the keyboard, but when I'm using my phone it does. The tests are run through the emulator, but could this be the probem?

I've tried hiding the keyboard before clicking on the text field but this didn't help.

**Update**

Try scrolling using this code;

```
        const tabContentBasic = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("tabContentBasic");
        tabContentBasic.scroll(Direction.down, 200, 0)
```

Here is my basic tab

```
  <TabContentItem>
    <ScrollView orientation="vertical">
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical" automationText="tabContentBasic">
        <Label text="Date of Purchase"></Label>
        <TextField automationText="date" hint="Date of Purchase" [(ngModel)]="_assetItem.date_of_purchase" class="input"></TextField>

        <Label text="Asset Name"></Label>
        <TextField automationText="name" hint="Asset Name" [(ngModel)]="_assetItem.name" class="input"></TextField>

        <Label text="Purchase Price"></Label>
        <TextField automationText="gross" hint="Asset Purchase Price" [(ngModel)]="_assetItem.gross_cents" class="input"></TextField>

        <Label text="Comment"></Label>
        <TextField automationText="comment" hint="Asset Comment" [(ngModel)]="_assetItem.comment" class="input"></TextField>

      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </TabContentItem>
```

Comment: Perhaps the textfield is beyond visible screen limit, did you try scrolling down.

Comment: Yes I've tried scrolling but it doesn't help